# CSS multiple animation keyframes sequence and delay not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I created 2 keyframes. The 1st keyframe is applied to all elements with class `.drop-in`. And the 2nd keyframe is specific to an element with class `.look-at-me`, when the 1st keyframe animation has finished.

The problem is, even though I have added a delay on the 2nd keyframe for the class `.look-at-me`, all animations are still occurring at the same time instead of applying the delay.

**Can someone help me fix this?**

Check my work here: **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/levraisey/pen/MYBJjq)**

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="box-list">
  <li>
    <div class="box drop-in">
      <h1>The Box</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box drop-in">
      <h1>The Box</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box drop-in look-at-me">
      <h1>The Box</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box drop-in">
      <h1>The Box</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**LESS :**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}

.box-list {
  list-style: none;

  li {
    width: 140px;
    height: 145px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 24px;
    position: relative;

    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .drop-in {
      -webkit-animation: drop-in-anim 0.3s forwards;
      -moz-animation: drop-in-anim 0.3s forwards;
      animation: drop-in-anim 0.3s forwards;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .look-at-me {
      -webkit-animation: drop-in-anim 0.3s forwards, look-at-me-anim 0.5s forwards;
      -moz-animation: drop-in-anim 0.3s forwards, look-at-me-anim 0.5s forwards;
      animation: drop-in-anim 0.3s forwards, look-at-me-anim 0.5s forwards;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 20s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0s, 20s;
      animation-delay: 0s, 20s;
    }

    &:nth-child(1) {
      .drop-in {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
        animation-delay: 0.2s;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      .drop-in {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
        animation-delay: 0.3s;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      .drop-in {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
        animation-delay: 0.4s;
      }
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      .drop-in {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
        animation-delay: 0.5s;
      }
    }

    .box {
      padding: 6px;
      border: 1px solid #333;
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 5;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

      &:hover,
      &.look-at-me {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
      }
    }
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes drop-in-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes drop-in-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes drop-in-anim {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes look-at-me-anim {
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.4); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.3); margin: 0 12px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes look-at-me-anim {
    50% { -moz-transform: scale(1.4); }
    75% { -moz-transform: scale(1.2); }
    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1.3); margin: 0 12px; }
}
@keyframes look-at-me-anim {
    50% { transform: scale(1.4); }
    75% { transform: scale(1.2); }
    100% { transform: scale(1.3); margin: 0 12px; }
}
```

Comment: Besides that, why not use a simple transform.scale with a transition delay?

Comment: Does not posting code matters? Besides, most of my codes are in jsfiddle or codepen to see. And if you look from the beginning of my membership I have posted codes in the past. If I understand what you're saying. Also my lifestyle is different then yours, so understand someone circumstances before making judgement. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: @Jonathan He has posted a fiddle and I think that is sufficient. If you have voted to close under "no  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" I think you should consider retracting your vote.

Comment: link rot happens. link only questions and answers should be edited to include both the code and the link to the demo. Then if the link does die someone can reproduce on their own.

Comment: @ThePragmatick I haven't, but I don't disagree with whoever did. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253500/2407212

Comment: @rlemon, now I understand why I should post codes. If `Jonathan` advised me and told me why instead of complaining and rebuking, then it wouldn't have gone this far. But the way `rlemon` explained it, that was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your delay with this.

```
&:nth-child(3) {
  .drop-in {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
  }
}
```

you could also write the delay in shorthand:

```
.look-at-me {
  -webkit-animation:drop-in-anim 0.3s ease-in 0.4s forwards,
   look-at-me-anim 0.5s ease-in 1s forwards;     
 }
```